# Mentionsinput directive for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm looking for a AngularJS directive thats support mentionsinput. Something like this one:
http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/

Is there any out there or somebody who can help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would autocomplete be good for this?

http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAutocomplete

Comment: Hmm I'm already using autocomplete (same as you posted). But in this case I want to mix free text with autocomplete. Like the Facebook comment box.

Comment: Are you already using jQuery in your code? If so, why not wrapping jquery-mentions-input with your own directive because I think there's not built-in directive for doing this?

Comment: Sorry, today im using typeahead for autocomplete. You can find it here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: @drphil were you able to find anything usefull? Seems like I am also trying to implement Facebook like comment box using angularUI typeahead.

Comment: @SLearner just found this and its exactly what I was looking for! Se:
http://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/#/

Comment: @drphil did you find how to get mentioned input data from  jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/# ?